# Would you interpret this image as a correct deconvolution process?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

I'm applying the function `conv2d_grad_wrt_inputs` in theano to deconv a feature map into the original image.

In the figure below the first image to the left is the input image which I'm applying convolution and the result is the feature map in the second image while the third image is the deconvolution process.

I'm applying the function into one feature maps using its kernel of size (7x7x3). the result is not convincing that it is doing a correct deconvolution as I see it repeated pattern of the kernel. Would you interpret this as a correct deconvolution process ?

[image]

---

### UPDATE

After reviewing the code I found that I was relaying on `input.reshape(batchsize, image channels, img_w, img_h)` to transform the image into the convolution shape which breaks the array structure before adding a transpose to the image. So I retrained the network by transposing the input input.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(b,c,x,y) and the result was clearly understandable. 
[image]

We can see from the image how feature map are truly correlated to the input image and pointing out which features from that map are activated by this input.

What I want to know here. Why the color channels are mixed up and the original color of the image are not mixed? As you can only see a mixture of color and not the real texture of the image.

Comment: Is the first image on the right or the left?  The middle image just looks black to me.  I can't see any features.  There really is no relationship between the left and the right. Something must be wrong but how would anyone be able to figure out what is wrong without more information.

Comment: to the left is the deconvolution. if you look the image in the middle you will se some texture in the corner similar to the image shape on the left. If it allowed to post the code here I'll do it.